# Find the limit: $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin(\tan\frac1x)$

Tags: limits

How do I find the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin(\tan\frac1x)$$

Comment: Change of variable and l'Hopital?  Please add some context to this bare problem statement question to avoid the impression you are simply paasing through an assigned exercise to your Readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set $x=\frac{1}{t}$. Note that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x \sin \left(\tan \frac{1}{x}\right)=\lim_{t \to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin (\tan t)}{t}$$
Now, note that $$\lim_{t \to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin (\tan t)}{t}=\lim_{t \to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin (\tan t)}{\tan t} \times \frac{\tan t}{t}=\lim_{t \to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin (\tan t)}{\tan t} \times \lim_{t \to 0^{+}}\frac{\tan t}{t}$$
Setting $\tan t =u$, the limit becomes $$\lim_{u \to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin u}{u} \times \lim_{t \to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin t}{t} \times \lim_{t \to 0^{+}} \frac{1}{\cos t}=1$$
As proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the limit as

\begin{align}
L:=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\sin\left(\tan\frac{1}{x}\right)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\tan\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}
\end{align}

Since both the numerator and the denominator tend to $0$ in the limit, this is an indeterminate form and we can apply L'Hospital's Rule.

\begin{align}
L&=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\tan\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}\\
&=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{x^2}\sec^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\cos\left(\tan\frac{1}{x}\right)}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\\
&=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sec^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\cos\left(\tan\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
\end{align}

By continuity of all the functions involved, we can pull the limits into the functions. Since $\frac{1}{x}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$, we have

> $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\sin\left(\tan\frac{1}{x}\right) = 1$$